# PHP Curl return 404 from aws but works from other host and even my machine

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, curl, ssh

Been banging my head over this for awhile. I have written php code to search the website https:paytm.com which works from the other hosting site I have been with earlier but not from AWS.

My machine is running ubuntu with php7, curl is installed and running. the search using curl works for other sites, curl https also works. the same code works brilliantly on the other host (via ssh as well as frontend), it even works from the browser.

The url I am trying to access is `curl -v 'https://search.paytm.com/search/?page_count=1&items_per_page=10&quality=high&curated=1&cat_tree=1&from=organic&channel=web&version=2&userQuery=iphone'`

Things I have checked:

1. The certificates are up to date
2. The code works fine on my machine and other hosting provider
3. AWS setup is ubuntu 12.04, running php
4. Setting up the machine again
5. Running the script from browser
6. Checking https curl on google, twitter, linkedIn from my aws setup, they work fine.

The resulting response coming from my AWS setup is:

```
    ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-200:/usr/local/share$ curl -v https://search.paytm.com/search/?page_count=1&items_per_page=10&quality=high&curated=1&cat_tree=1&from=organic&channel=web&version=2&userQuery=iphone
    [1] 12595
    [2] 12596
    [3] 12597
    [4] 12598
    [5] 12599
    [6] 12600
    [7] 12601
    [8] 12602
    ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-200:/usr/local/share$ * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
    *   Trying 96.6.72.42...
    * Connected to search.paytm.com (96.6.72.42) port 443 (#0)
    * successfully set certificate verify locations:
    *   CAfile: none
      CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
    * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
    * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
    * SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    * Server certificate:
    *    subject: C=IN; ST=Uttar Pradesh; L=Noida; O=One 97 Communications Limited; CN=secure.paytm.in
    *    start date: 2015-10-29 00:00:00 GMT
    *    expire date: 2016-10-28 23:59:59 GMT
    *    subjectAltName: search.paytm.com matched
    *    issuer: C=US; O=GeoTrust Inc.; CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
    *    SSL certificate verify ok.
    > GET /search/?page_count=1 HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
    > Host: search.paytm.com
    > Accept: */*
    > 
    
    404 Not Found
    
    404 Not Found
    nginx
    
    
    * Connection #0 to host search.paytm.com left intact
```

The result coming from the different hosting provider (and from my own machine is):

```
    [ps527167]$ curl -v https://search.paytm.com/search/?page_count=1&items_per_page=10&quality=high&curated=1&cat_tree=1&from=organic&channel=web&version=2&userQuery=iphone
    [1] 26241
    [2] 26242
    [3] 26243
    [4] 26244
    [5] 26245
    [6] 26246
    [7] 26247
    [8] 26248
    [2]   Done                    items_per_page=10
    [3]   Done                    quality=high
    [4]   Done                    curated=1
    [5]   Done                    cat_tree=1
    [6]   Done                    from=organic
    [7]-  Done                    channel=web
    [ps527167]$ * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
    *   Trying 23.218.97.132...
    * Connected to search.paytm.com (23.218.97.132) port 443 (#0)
    * successfully set certificate verify locations:
    *   CAfile: none
      CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
    * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
    * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
    * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
    * SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    * Server certificate:
    *    subject: C=IN; ST=Uttar Pradesh; L=Noida; O=One 97 Communications Limited; CN=secure.paytm.in
    *    start date: 2015-10-29 00:00:00 GMT
    *    expire date: 2016-10-28 23:59:59 GMT
    *    subjectAltName: search.paytm.com matched
    *    issuer: C=US; O=GeoTrust Inc.; CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G3
    *    SSL certificate verify ok.
    > GET /search/?page_count=1 HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
    > Host: search.paytm.com
    > Accept: */*
```

```
     HTTP/1.1 200 OK
     Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
     Server openresty is not blacklisted
     Server: openresty
     Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
     Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
     X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
     X-PAYTM-SRV-ID: pawslmktsearchapp04
     Date: Mon, 06 Jun 2016 15:22:18 GMT
     Content-Length: 907
     Connection: keep-alive
     Connection #0 to host search.paytm.com left intact
```

```
    {"result_type":"grid","default_sorting_param":"sort_relevance=1","meta":{"version":"1.0.0","query":null,"category":[],"mappedQuery":null},"sorting_keys":[{"name":"Relevance","urlParams":"sort_relevance","default":"sort_relevance=1"},{"name":"New","urlParams":"sort_new","default":"sort_new=1"},{"name":"Price","urlParams":"sort_price","default":"sort_price=0"}],"frontend_filters":[],"filters":[{"title":"In-Stock","values":[{"id":"0","name":"0"},{"id":"1","name":"In-Stock"}],"filter_param":"availability","type":"boolean"}],"search_suggestion":null,"has_more":false,"total_count":0,"grid_layout":[],"featured_products":[],"related_searches":[],"search_user_id":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.NjZmN2M3OWMtODllZC00OTRjLWI2MDYtNjNiODhlNWE4MTZi.7RvVFv4nDejWf4joXgy_TMdVaaQRTC2F-QPP6FvU_gQ","search_id":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.N2JhYzJkNjYtZWE4Ny00OTVmLWE2NzktMTlmM2QwNzY2OWI2.o9dbkUxVEWk8j8PdZnafMzxuAIzubTY9TJFiwyhEy8Q"}
    [1]-  Done                    curl -v https://search.paytm.com/search/?page_count=1
    [8]+  Done                    version=2
```

Really stumped as to what to do, tried searching stackoverflow to the core and found few solutions like setting cookies or user agent but both doesn't work, also if you see the user-agent string for the other hosting is also set to the same and yet it returns the correct response, heck it even runs the same version of ubuntu. Would be awesome if I could get any help regarding this from the community.

To wrap it up, my skill level in ubuntu, terminal, ssh, etc is just newfound so you might have to lay down the terms and help in basic way... sorry for that.

Comment: Can you paste the Security group rules for your EC2 instance?

Comment: Inbound
HTTP  TCP  80  0.0.0.0/0
SSH  TCP  22  0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS  TCP  443  0.0.0.0/0

Outbound
All traffic  All  All  0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Please include the output from `host search.paytm.com` on each of your working and non-working systems.

Comment: **Non-working -->**
`ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-200:/usr/local/share$ host search.paytm.com

search.paytm.com is an alias for search.paytm.com.edgekey.net.
search.paytm.com.edgekey.net is an alias for e9976.b.akamaiedge.net.
e9976.b.akamaiedge.net has address 96.6.72.42`


**Working -->**
`[ps527167]$ host search.paytm.com

search.paytm.com is an alias for search.paytm.com.edgekey.net.
search.paytm.com.edgekey.net is an alias for e9976.b.akamaiedge.net.
e9976.b.akamaiedge.net has address 23.218.97.132`

Comment: **Working From Mac -->**
`host search.paytm.com
search.paytm.com is an alias for search.paytm.com.edgekey.net.
search.paytm.com.edgekey.net is an alias for e9976.b.akamaiedge.net.
e9976.b.akamaiedge.net has address 23.52.64.198`

Comment: What happens if you put the IP from the second server in the first server's `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, sorry... am in the unknown territory over here, can you tell me how. should I nano it or something?

Comment: Yes, just add a line like `23.218.97.132 search.paytm.com` to the file.

Comment: Same 404 page after putting it in the hosts file and restarting apache

Comment: @rrauenza I am writing to Akamai but redirecting host hasn't worked as well.

Comment: Ok, I just spawned a new AWS Instance just to test whether curl from there will work and it hasn't worked over there as well so it looks like that the dns issue could be the case. @Barmar I tried host search.paytm.com and it still is going to 96.6.72.42, Anyway to force it

Comment: The `host` command doesn't look in `/etc/hosts`, it just queries DNS. But `curl` should use `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Ahh.... I see it picks up when I curl but the response is the same. Maybe they have put a blacklist on the AWS ids and MediaTemple

Comment: If I put `96.6.72.42 search.paytm.com` in my `/etc/hosts` and run the `curl` command, I get a `200 OK` on the query, and I'm definitely hitting `96.6.72.42`.  So your theory of a blacklist may be correct.

Comment: Perhaps try asking around at http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/discussion/

Comment: This is their undocumented api for search of products while paywithpaytm is for integrating their wallet (kinda like PayPal)... I have asked them but being so big I doubt they are going to address it. For now, Since I know that this is not a configuration issue but a blacklist one, I will use the script at Dreamhost to do this. Thanks for all the debug and support guys... especially Barmar and rrauenza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the AWS entire range of IP is blacklisted which is the reason for the error to pop up.

Answer (score 1):

`search.paytm.com` is being hosted on the Akamai CDN, so different clients are routed to different servers. Notice that your first connection went to `96.6.72.42` and the second one went to `23.218.97.132`. When I look up the hostname I get different IPs, alternating between `104.97.19.53` and `23.203.115.39`; I'm located in Boston using Comcast, and traceroute shows that those are located in Comcast datacenters in Boston and New York City.

For some reason, the page you want is only located on the second server. This is a problem with their configuration, you need to contact them.

Comment: I doubt they are going to reply... Also, I do think that since I tried hosting from DreamHost (US Based) and my own machine (India) and both resolved to 23.218.97.132 while the AWS setup (singapore) resolved differently means that they might be doing load balancing (or a really bad way of geo-locating) but do let me know if you think I am wrong

Comment: I used to work at Akamai. The algorithms are very complicated, based on geographic location, network proximity, and measured latency. FYI, I get a different IP: `104.97.19.53`

Comment: Oh... well, I guess then I am fighting a lost cause if the problem is their server based :(

Comment: Hmm, the problem seems to be at your end, or they're blocking your first server's IP. I just tried putting both IPs in my /etc/hosts file, and it worked in both cases.

Comment: Yeah, I do think the problem is from my end. But I recently shifted server and they didn't block the first one so I don't think they blocked this.
Also, I tested the same thing from another one of the setup (buzzida.com) in mediatemple and that is also not going through. So we have two setups (AWS and mediatemple hosting) which don't work and two (Dreamhost and my Mac) which does. Any idea what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're not escaping your url.  The `&`'s mean something to the shell.

Try the following:

```
curl -v 'https://search.paytm.com/search/?page_count=1&items_per_page=10&quality=high&curated=1&cat_tree=1&from=organic&channel=web&version=2&userQuery=iphone'
```

The clue is this output:

```
[1] 26241
[2] 26242
[3] 26243
[4] 26244
[5] 26245
[6] 26246
[7] 26247
[8] 26248
[2]   Done                    items_per_page=10
[3]   Done                    quality=high
[4]   Done                    curated=1
[5]   Done                    cat_tree=1
[6]   Done                    from=organic
[7]-  Done                    channel=web
```

Those are shell background jobs.  It is literally trying to run the following commands and put them into the background:

```
$ curl -v 'https://search.paytm.com/search/?page_count=1 &
$ items_per_page=10 &
$ quality=high &
[... and so on ...]
```

Comment: Putting the quotes didn't work :(
Would also like to add the same command from Dreamhost ssh and mac goes correctly.

Comment: Hi, please edit your question and put the quotes in and show the results with quotes, because right now the lack of quotes make it difficult to root cause your problem.

Comment: I just tried it with quotes.  Works for me.  I got a `200 OK`.  Ah but it also works with  just `curl -v 'https://search.paytm.com/search/?page_count=1'`

Comment: Edited, Yes... that's why I am stumped. It works on my mac and DreamHost server as well. I have even tried to verify curl (https) for google and twitter through aws and that goes in correctly.

Comment: @rrauenza `404 Not found` refers to the `/search/` script itself, the parameters that are missing because of the incorrect quoting shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the 2 systems resolve to 2 completely different IP ranges on the same host name suggests that the target IP was recently changed, yet your system that fails is still getting the old IP as a DNS response.

Suggest using Google's free DNS servers..
https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#linux

Comment: Did you miss the messages that said that the name was NOT in the DNS cache? So they're not caching an old IP. Akamai addresses are supposed to be different for different clients, that's how they do load balancing and reduce latency.